# Why "ambiguous reference to overloaded definition" for methods with different signatures?

Tags: scala, overload-resolution

I know there are a number of other questions about this error, but the others are pretty clear why there's an error. In my case, I can't understand why.  Here's a short example:

```
trait A {
  def text: String = "abc"
}
case object B extends A {
  def text(s: Seq[String]): String = s.mkString
}
```

Now, calling `B.text` I would expect to be unambiguously resolved to the method inherited from the base trait since the one in object B doesn't even match the calling signature... but yet, error!

`<console>:13: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method text in object B of type (s: Seq[String])String
and  method text in trait A of type => String
match expected type ?
       B.text
         ^`

Is this "normal"/expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B.text` can be considered on the one hand as calling `text` method from trait `A` and on the other hand as eta-expanded method from `B` that will return the function of type `Seq[String] => String`

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to indicate to the compiler which method I'm interested in based on the return type? `A.text` returns `String` while `B.text` returns `Seq[String] => String`.  So is there a way to specify that I want `B.text` to call the `A.text` method? (other than `B.asInstanceOf[A].text`)